# Unique Array by comparing elements of array React JS

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have this array

```
array = [
         {id: "one", title: "new 1"},
         {id: "two", parent_id: "132132", title: "new 2"},
         {id: "three", parent_id: "132132", title: "new 3"},
         {id: "four", parent_id: "132132", title: "new 1"},
         {id: "one", parent_id: "132132", title: "new 1"}
        ]
```

We need

```
array = [
         {id: "two", parent_id: "132132", title: "new 2"},
         {id: "three", parent_id: "132132", title: "new 3"},
         {id: "four", parent_id: "132132", title: "new 1"},
         {id: "one", parent_id: "132132", title: "new 1"}
        ]
```

We need to compare elements to get unique array with different avoiding other elements

I have tried using this method

```
uniqueArray = (arr) => {
  return arr.filter((e, i, arr) => arr.findIndex(e2 => Object.keys(e2).every(prop => e2[prop] === e[prop])) === i);
};
```

Comment: As far as i can see all values are unique in this array, no duplicates. Be more specific based on what exactly do you want to filter this array.

Comment: You mean to say with unique `id`? What should be the behaviour for the duplicates? Which ones take precedence? The last one?

Comment: yes please.  unique with id element

Comment: Also, need in return parent id 's hash

Comment: @ArpitVaishnav in the example array, the only one that is excluded does not have a parent_id. Is it safe to say that's the case for all duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `Array.reduce` for this kind of things:

```
const filteredArr = arr.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const exists = acc.find(item => item.id === current.id);
  if (!exists) {
    return acc.concat([current]);
  } else {
    return acc;
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to return object without the property of parentId. If so you can use this.

```
array.filter(arr => arr.hasOwnProperty("parentId"))
```

Comment: thanks , how can we compare with id and keep parent id hash?

Comment: What you will get after this filter an array of objects with parentId properties. Do you want to also store the objects without the parentId somewhere else?